# Metro UI CSS - Dropdown menu is not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, windows-8, metro-ui-css

I am using **METRO UI CSS**. I implemented *dropdown menu* . It looks good. But the dropdown list is not showing.

I used example from the following link:

[Horizontal menu with dropdown](http://metroui.org.ua/menus.html).

I added the following files from the latest [METRO UI CSS](https://github.com/olton/Metro-UI-CSS/archive/master.zip) package to my *html* code.

```
<link href="metroui/css/metro-bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="metroui/css/metro-bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="metroui/docs/css/iconFont.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="metroui/docs/js/prettify/prettify.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="metroui/docs/css/docs.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Load JavaScript Libraries -->
<script src="metroui/js/metro-dropdown.js"></script>
<script type="dropdown.js"></script>
<script src="metroui/docs/js/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="metroui/docs/js/jquery/jquery.widget.min.js"></script>
<script src="metroui/docs/js/jquery/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
<script src="metroui/docs/js/prettify/prettify.js"></script>
<script src="metroui/docs/js/holder.js"></script>

<!-- Metro UI CSS JavaScript plugins -->
<script src="metroui/docs/js/load-metro.js"></script>
```

Any help will be appreciated !

Comment: any error in browser console? make sure all files loading correctly.

Comment: Thanks for that point !! It was the problem !! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following - it's working fine for me:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script> 
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
<link href="Scripts/metro-ui/css/metro-bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="Scripts/metro-ui/css/metro-bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="Scripts/metro-ui/css/iconFont.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="Scripts/metro-ui/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/metro-ui/js/jquery.widget.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/metro-ui/js/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/metro-ui/js/metro.min.js"></script> </pre>
```

And also add  `class="metro"` to your `<body>` like this: `<body class="metro">`

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Navbar dropdowns only work with files in the root folder. Only the css/js in the docs folder seems to work correctly. I have tried all other combinations and they do not workYou have to have all your files in the root folder or the navbar drop downs wont work.

Non navbar dropdowns work anywhere.

Only the docs css/js versions work. The other versions do not

UPDATE:

In load-metro.js you need to change the path from relative to absolute.

```
$(function(){
    if ((document.location.host.indexOf('.dev') > -1) || (document.location.host.indexOf('modernui') > -1) ) {
        $("<script/>").attr('src', '/docs/js/metro/metro-loader.js').appendTo($('head'));
    } else {
        $("<script/>").attr('src', '/docs/js/metro.min.js').appendTo($('head'));
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

From author:

> metro.min.js includes all js metro components. Check your main container for class metro. If your build dropdown from ajax, set global variable METRO_AUTO_REINIT to true. See more here https://github.com/olton/Metro-UI-CSS/issues/574

I have added to header tag and it work.

`<script src="metroui/docs/js/load-metro.js"></script>
<script>var METRO_AUTO_REINIT = true;</script>`

Comment: Please provide some explanation as well, to not only provide the OP with working code, but also teach him something.

Answer (score -1):

Metro UI depends on jQuery, you should include jQuery first, then Metro UI.

```
<!-- Load JavaScript Libraries -->
<script src="metroui/docs/js/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="metroui/docs/js/jquery/jquery.widget.min.js"></script>
<script src="metroui/docs/js/jquery/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
<script src="metroui/js/metro-dropdown.js"></script>
<script src="dropdown.js"></script>
<script src="metroui/docs/js/prettify/prettify.js"></script>
<script src="metroui/docs/js/holder.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you run it on server. Please put it into htdocs folder of the server like XAMPP or WAMP.

If you run it by "Double click" the links will be like

```
file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/Metro-UI-CSS-master/docs/navbar.html
```

If you run it on server the links will be like

```
http://localhost/Metro-UI-CSS-master/docs/navbar.html
```

Whick corrected ways are you?